# Reading tags in an XML CLOB column

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I've searched several posts here and tried different approaches. I don't get errors but I also don't get output.
In our system we store incoming xml transactions in a CLOB column `L80T2.tridata`, now users want to get warned when a new transaction comes so that they can check if all important fields in the DB are populated.

In the example I would like to have as output the PartId i.e. `<Id>R31312/CL7C</Id>`

Here is the full xml

```
<MaXML_Envelope version="0140"xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx.kom/Distro ../../../../mastd/xsd/MaXMLDoc/0140_PartUpdate_0100.xsd ">
<PartUpdate version="0100">
    <ControlArea>
        <Sender>
            <Division>A1</Division>
            <Confirmation>0</Confirmation>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2022-02-15T00:00:00Z</CreationDateTime>
        <RefId>
            <ReferenceId>90000206</ReferenceId>
        </RefId>
        <TransactionType>LP04</TransactionType>
        <SenderId>TRNM</SenderId>
        <ReceiverId>FMHW</ReceiverId>
    </ControlArea>
    <DataArea>
        <DataBaseTransaction sequence="1">
            <PartUpdate>
                <PartId>
===>                 <Id>R31312/CL7C</Id>
                     <Revision>9105</Revision>
                     <Division>A1</Division>
                 </PartId>
                 <Description>1606058</Description>
                 <UnitType/>
                 <PartToleranceArea>
                     <Inspection>N</Inspection>
                 </PartToleranceArea>
                 <UserArea>
                     <Wadmkey/>
                     <Description>1606058</Description>
                     <LanguageDescr_Segment sequence="1">
                         <DescrLanguage>EN</DescrLanguage>
                         <Description>1606058</Description>
                     </LanguageDescr_Segment>
                     <PartType>C</PartType>
                     <PartWeight>0.0</PartWeight>
                     <PartWeightUnit>KGM</PartWeightUnit>
                     <SingleUnitInstance/>
                     <HandlingUnitInstance/>
                     <PackCode/>
                     <ComCode/>
                 </UserArea>
            </PartUpdate>
        </DataBaseTransaction>
    </DataArea>
</PartUpdate>
</MaXML_Envelope>
```

I have done so far the following query (sqlplus)

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
    'declare default element namespace "http://www.xxx.kom/Distro ../../../../mastd/xsd/MaXMLDoc/0140_PartUpdate_0100.xsd"; (: :)
    /PartUpdate/DataArea/DataBaseTransaction/PartId/Id/text()'     
    PASSING XMLTYPE(L80T2.tridata)
    RETURNING CONTENT
) myxmldata,  L79T1.trno, L79T1.comtype
from L79T1
inner join L80T2 on (L80T2.trno = L79T1.trno)
where L79T1.trtype = '702'
```

and here is the output of above query

```
MYXMLDATA
------------------
      TRNO COMT
---------- ----

 161657423 MQS


 161672521 MQS


 161666181 MQS
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm expecting something like:

```
 MYXMLDATA        TRNO COMT
 ----------- --------- ----
 R31312/CL7C 161657423 MQS
 V34132/AB   161672521 MQS
 OR-12BC     161666181 MQS
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is missing the root `MaXML_Envelope` node, and the intermediate `PartUpdate` node.

So this:

```
/PartUpdate/DataArea/DataBaseTransaction/PartId/Id/text()
```

should be:

```
/MaXML_Envelope/PartUpdate/DataArea/DataBaseTransaction/PartUpdate/PartId/Id/text()
```

You also don't need to declare a default namespace, at least with what you've shown; but your XML should be declaring the `xsi` namespace (or must be, or you wouldn't see the result you do now; so you've lost that in posting?).

And you might also want to call `getStringVal()` to get a `varchar2` result.

In full:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
    '/MaXML_Envelope/PartUpdate/DataArea/DataBaseTransaction/PartUpdate/PartId/Id/text()'     
    PASSING XMLTYPE(L80T2.tridata)
    RETURNING CONTENT
).getStringVal() myxmldata,  L79T1.trno, L79T1.comtype
from L79T1
inner join L80T2 on (L80T2.trno = L79T1.trno)
where L79T1.trtype = '702'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c945cb9be3253e9b2372d9943a1e3527)

Comment: Great! Absolutely great! thanks

Comment: the xsi namespace is not present, I copied pasted the whole data, nothing less nothing more :-D

Comment: I see now that the above works just for one instance of `<DataBaseTransaction sequence="1">` but if I have more i.e. `<DataBaseTransaction sequence="2">` and then `<DataBaseTransaction sequence="3">` etc ? The output is all compressed in one row. Is there a solution here? Thanks

Comment: You probably want to switch from XMLQuery to XMLTable, depending on the output you want - multiple rows per trno (with the sequence number included?), or aggregates, or something else? Multiple rows is fairly straightforward; look at XMLTable, and then if you can't make that work, probably best to ask a new question with an XML document that has multiples (but maybe you can cut out some of the data you aren't using for posting, to make it shorter?) and the exact output you are trying to get.

Comment: I'm learning thanks, I'll look for XMLTable docs and if I get stuck I'll post a new question